# Tracking users' clicks and page visits in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, tracking

I would like to monitor users' page visits and clicks in my Rails app to make recommendations. My questions are:

- Is there a Rails gem for this, or Google Analytics is the standard? If latter is true, then how should I link a page visit to a particular user profile?
- It is typical in Rails to have a  section in application.html.erb, which is shared for all pages. If I add Google Analytics pageview tracking code to  in application.html.erb, will it be able to track all individual pages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are other ways, but the vast majority probably use Google Analytics.  Several gems exist that help you integrate with GA to get at the data.  See here:  https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Web_Analytics.

Based on your first question, it seems you may want more insight than GA can provide.  I've used ClickTale (http://www.clicktale.com) and Woopra (http://www.woopra.com) before, to good effect.  This article lists several other alternatives, too - notice the high marks for Clicky:  http://imimpact.com/web-stats-alternatives-to-google-analytics/.

Google Analytics (and almost all of these others) will take care of your second question automatically whenever the user loads a new page, since it keyed by URL.  That means that, although you put the GA script code in a single place, each unique page is tracked individually.

If you have AJAX requests that change that page without changing the URL, you'll need to dig in to the GA script API.  Essentially you'll need to push a new url (possibly with a # in it) whenever you want to track an AJAX-driven link/button click.  See here:  http://davidwalsh.name/ajax-analytics

Comment: Thanks for your super fast answer!

Answer (score 9):

I am biased, but I would recommend checking out [impressionist](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist), if you need to integrate the page views into the app in real-time.  With analytics you will always have some lag time and you are also relying on an external dependency.  Impressionist is good if you need this kind of control, but if you are just looking for simple metrics and don't need to pull them into the app, then analytics is probably the way to go.

Comment: I really need to get used to "the Rails way", i.e. someone has probably already solved my problem :) I was very close to writing this exact functionality from scratch when I found your answer.. thanks!

Comment: impressionist uses the database to increase the stats which is sometime slow in high workload. Checkout the gem https://github.com/tranvictor/lion_attr

Answer (score 6):

Check out Ahoy, at https://github.com/ankane/ahoy. With just a few lines of code in your app, you can track page views and tie them to user accounts.

You can further customize Ahoy to track custom events, both the client (with JavaScript) and server.

Ahoy does not depend on any third-party services.